# Making a lager from an ale recipe

Tags: lagering

My question involves fermentation of an ale recipe into a lager. Is it possible to brew an ale recipe and then ferment it with a lager yeast at lagering temperatures? Will the fermented wort have the qualities (taste and color) of a fermented lager?

Comment: The best option for me in making a lager at warm temps is the WLP810, San Francisco Lager yeast. I just made my second all grain version and it was phenomenal (after making many partial mash/extract versions that were very good) Easy recipe: - 6 lbs Pilsner Malt - 3 lbs Vienna - 2 lbs Munich (what, no specialty malts ? none needed) - Hallertau at 60 and 30 - Saaz at 10 1 week primary, 10-14 days secondary or until fermentation done. If kegged I go 20 psi for 72 hours then let the beer and bubbles make friends for another few days. The longer it stays in the keg the better it gets. At 6 weeks y

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can take an ale recipe and use lager yeast at suggested temps.

As for taste, it will depend on your recipe. Yes, the yeast imparts flavor to your beer, but, you can't make a medium body ale and expect a light lager at the end.

Comment: actually, in my experience, there are some lager yeasts, which tend to do exactly that. It depends a lot on attenuation and residual sweetness.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it.  Tastes and smells like a lager.  I liked it better than the ale version but I think I just prefer lagers.  Pitch a lot of yeast if you decide to try it.